# Registering OLE server in Delphi XE5 and non-pascal codes in ridl file

Tags: delphi, pascal, ole

I am writing an exe OLE server to embed it in my own application. I am running OLE server (exe) with `/regserver` parameter as a normal user and I am getting following error:

> Error accessing the OLE registry

I don't need any other programs to use this server. It is just for my own client and it will not be a DLL. Is there a way to register it as standard user?

Other problem is that i see codes which are not pascal in ridl file. Types of properties are C not Pascal. For example i see DATE but i don't see TDateTime in the list. I am using XE5.

Comment: We don't know in detail what you are doing, why you get an error, and so on. Why do you expect to find Pascal in an IDL file? There's no reason for you to expect that.

Comment: Your OLE server is trying to register in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE by default, which a standard user does not have access to. Either elevate your server during registration, or else register in HKEY_CURRENT_USER instead.  RIDL is not Pascal, or even C. It is *Reduced IDL*, which is its own language and syntax. Delphi has a RIDL compiler. And `DATE` is a standard OLE data type.

Comment: David it is just a workaround. I just need to create an OLE server to prevent freezing main app. Main app will embed child app. If I use SetParent() and if child app freezes somehow, main app will freeze too. So that is the solution to prevent it. I am just calling OLE server using /regserver param.

Comment: @RemyLebeau i am just running my OLE server using /regserver param. And i think it tries to register in HKLM. How can i register it in HKCU?

Comment: What you need to do is describe in detail what you have done, but do so in the **question** rather than in comments.

Comment: I have created a blank OLE server. That's what i have done so far. Nothing else...

Comment: Why do you think an OLE server will prevent your freezing problem?  In any case, you have to change your OLE server's registration to register in HKCU. See [REGSERVER bug in COM EXE server](http://www.borlandtalk.com/regserver-bug-in-com-exe-server-vt93452.html) and the [TComServer.PerUserRegistration](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.Win.ComObj.TComServerObject.PerUserRegistration) property.

Comment: You said "I am getting following error". We don't know what you are doing exactly that provokes this error. Please stop leaking details in comments. Please edit the question. Please read the site help to learn more about how to ask well.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan is it ok now?

Comment: @RemyLebeau well let's think about flash player. They are loaded by browser and if anything goes wrong browser doesn't freeze. So I am trying to findout if i can fix it by creating ole server.

Comment: A frozen OLE server can still freeze its host.  The host has to communicate with the OLE server, and that communication can freeze if the server is not responsive.  Ask Adobe how they managed to get around that in Flash.

Comment: If the host can not communicate, it can just kill it. Am i right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use switch "/REGSERVERPERUSER"

I use XE5, it work.

Delphi write corresponding register keys

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`PerUserRegistration`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Win.ComObj.TComServerObject.PerUserRegistration) to ensure that your COM server self-registers to the per-user HKCU hive. Or simply write the registry settings yourself. Which is the recommended approach anyway if you are writing an install program.

[RIDL](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/RIDL_File) is a flavour of Interface Description Language ([IDL](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_description_language)). It is used to describe the interface of your COM server. It is not Pascal. It's not passed to a Pascal compiler. It's processed by a tool that understands RIDL. Everything is as expected.

Comment: Do i need to write it before Application.Initialize; ? And is the code TComServerObject.PerUserRegistration := True; ?

Comment: Also can you please kindly tell me where can i write registry settings? I mean which key is it and required values?

Comment: Set the property during initialization. After the com server object has been created. MS document COM registration registry settings on MSDN.